# Нужно ли тут использовать ID и как выбрать нужный элемент?

Tags: javascript, html, css

К примеру, у меня есть html-файл, содержащий кучу продуктов, еды проще говоря, каждая имеет btn "Order", и при нажатии перебрасывает на "Order.html", где по умолчанию стоит только один и тот же продукт с одной и той же ценой.
Как реализовать то, чтобы при нажатии на один из перечня продуктов, была картинка и цена именно его, а не продукта  по умолчанию?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Покажите ваш код, где и как вы это пытаетесь реализовать. Если вам нужна просто теория, то да, такое сделать можно, допустим с помощью get параметров в url